# Python evernote api Error

Tags: python, django-views, evernote

Trying to build app that connects with Evernote API, in Python/Django. For the below code i get the following error message: " 'Store' object has no attribute 'NoteFilter' " from http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Svc_NoteStore One can see, that NoteFilter is attribute of NoteStore.

```
def list(request):
    nbname="mihkel's notebook"
    client = EvernoteClient(token=token, sandbox=False)

    note_store = client.get_note_store()
    notebooks = note_store.listNotebooks()

    for nb in notebooks:
        if nbname == nb.name:
            nb = nb
            filter = note_store.NoteFilter()
            filter.notebookGuid = nb.guid
            notelist = note_store.findNotes(token,filter,0,10)
        break

    return render_to_response('list.html', {'nb': nb, 'notelist':notelist})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
from evernote.edam.notestore import NoteStore
....
....
def list.. :
    ...
    Filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
```

Answer (score 0):

**notestore/ttypes.py has the definition for NoteFilter**

Some of the examples in the API code import like this

```
import evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore as NoteStore
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
```

Not sure if this would be an acceptable way to correct, but I added this:

```
import evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes as NoteStoreTypes
```

and created my filter like this:

```
filter = NoteStoreTypes.NoteFilter()
```